# Why can't my css apply on localhost.3000?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-style-loader

MY INDEX.CSS CANNOT APPLY ON MY LOCALHOST.300. I TRIED TO INSTALL THE CSS LOADER AND STUFF BUT IT STILL DOESN'T WORKING, ANYBODY CAN HELP ME?!
This is my Header.js:
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
const Header = ({title}) => {
return (

```
            <h1>{title}</h1>
        </header>
            )
        }
        Header.defaultProps ={
          title:'Task Tracker  '  
        }
        Header.propTypes={
            title:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        }
// css in js
       // const headingStyle = {
           // color:'red', 
           // backgroundColor:'blue'
       // }
export default Header
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./index.css"
import Header from "./components/Header";
 function App() {
  return (
<div className="Container">
 <Header  />
</div>
 )
}

export default App
```

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App'; 
import * as reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
require('./index.css');


ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode> 
    <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my index.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.task {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task.reminder {
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

.task h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.add-form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.form-control label {
  display: block;
}

.form-control input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.form-control-check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-control-check label {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-control-check input {
  flex: 2;
  height: 20px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

My 4 files( index.css, App.js, Header.js, and index.js) are inside my components folder which is inside my src folder

This is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-task-number",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-build-dist": "^0.0.8",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:dist": "react-build-dist",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0"
  }
}
```

This is webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'App.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },

     // Relevant bit of config for style loader and css loader:
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        // the order of `use` is important!
        use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
      },
    ]
  },
};
```

This is webpack.config.prod.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    entry: 'apps/index.js',
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/*.*']),
    ],
    externals: {
        react: 'react',
        'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    },
});
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and don't YELL AT US.

Answer (score 0):

Because you capitalized the 'Container' in your JSX and the class name in your css is lower case

Comment: can you be more specific? Where is JSX? i'm sorry i'm just a begginner

Comment: oooh it works thank you man! god blessed you!

Comment: you should mark my answer as correct then =] glad I could help